# Adjusting width / horizontalAlignment with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following layout achieved in `SwiftUI`:

```
VStack {
  TextField(...)
  TextField(...)
  Button(...)
}
```

[image]

I tried making my VStack to be 50% of the superview, so I added the following modifier:

```
VStack { ... }
  .relativeWidth(0.5)
```

[image]

Not quite 50% of the superview, but I'm more interested in achieve horizontal centering. Anyone know how to achieve that in SwiftUI?

There's a `alignmentGuide(_:computeValue:)` modifier that's available, but I'm struggling to give the correct inputs to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use some spacers and HStack ...

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @State var myText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                TextField($myText, placeholder: Text("Email"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .textContentType(.username)

                TextField($myText, placeholder: Text("Password"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .textContentType(.password)

                Button(action: {
                    // Do your login thing here
                }) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
             Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way than spacers?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be center aligned already. **Letting the HStack know how much width to occupy** would finish the job perfectly. Above code by @SMP after modifications and **without spacers** would look like this:

```
struct LoginView : View {
    @State var myText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                TextField($myText, placeholder: Text("Email"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .textContentType(.username)
                TextField($myText, placeholder: Text("Password"))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                Button(action: {
                    // Do your login thing here
                }) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
            .relativeWidth(0.7)
        }
        .relativeWidth(1)
    }
}
```